# How can I include a large-scale image in an A4 Word 2010 document?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, documents

I would like to be able to include large-scale images with my Word 2010 documents. For example, a diagram produced as an A3 landscape image. How can I include it with the document, without shrinking it down to fit the A4 portrait document (eg, having it so that there's a "click to enlarge" function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature in Microsoft Word, however you can insert a section break and make that particular page with the image a different size from the rest of the document. Therefore you can resize the page to A3 and insert the image as full size without disrupting the rest of the document.

To do this you need to [insert two section breaks](https://web.archive.org/web/20130327000524/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-a-section-break-HA010031073.aspx) (new page) and then in the blank page that is created [select the paper size](https://web.archive.org/web/20131024004857/http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/word-help/select-paper-size-HP005189493.aspx) before inserting your image.

Comment: Thanks - any idea how to change the page size of that particular page?

Comment: @James, I edited my post with further information incase you didn't see.

Comment: @Adam link for paper size selection doesn't work anymore

Comment: @BarryChapman, Thanks for the alert. It's fixed now.

Comment: the link is broken, would you mind updating it?

Comment: @Ted it's fixed now